# Does the principle of complete induction imply the well-ordering principle

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Proof: Assume the PCI. Let $T$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Then $T$ has some element $x$. Then $\{1,2,...,x-1\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N} - T$. By the PCI, $x$ is an element of $\mathbb{N}-T$. This is a contradiction, because $x$ is an element of $T$ and $x$ is an element of $\mathbb{N}-T$. Therefore $T$ has a smallest element.

Is this proof valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is not valid. You use the Well-Ordering principle to prove the Well-Ordering Principle. In particular you choose an x, and then you assume that $\mathbb{N} - T$ contains all elements less than x, which can only happen if x was the smallest element to begin with.